# cannot open input file Aggregation.lib while build Doxygen source with Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator, doxygen

I'm using:

- Qt 4.8.4
- Qt Creator 2.7.0
- Qt Creator source 2.7.0
- Doxygen source Revision 57

Building [Doxygen (Doxygen plugin for Qt) source](http://svn.kofee.org/dl.php?repname=QtCreator-Doxygen&path=/trunk/&isdir=1) [svn.kofee.org] with Qt 4.8.4 for Desktop – MSVC2010 and QtCreator 2.7.0 output the following:

> -1: error: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Aggregation.lib'

Answer (score 0):

The plugin needs to be built against a fully compiled *in situ* qtcreator on Windows, unnecessary files are stripped from the distribution package but the compiler needs them to link the object codes together. You should ask on the website for a slightly quicker answer :)

Comment: I did build the plugin against a fully compiled QtCreator.
When you say the website, you mean Qt forums? if yes I already asked there as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the plugin's website. It is not affiliated with Qt (formerly Trolltech, Nokia or Digia nowadays). So, you obviously didn't use the command line configuration properly or made a mistake in editing the .pro file. Please review the [wiki](http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/wiki) and if unsuccessfull, directly [bug us](http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/issues/new) with full config/compile log and system info.